# $a,b,c \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $a^7+b^7+c^7=45$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Do there exist integers $a,b,c$ such that $a^7+b^7+c^7=45$?

[I have an ugly argument for a negative answer, is it possible to give a "manual" solution?]

Comment: By pigeonhole I would say that two of them have the same sign, the 3rd must be of the opposite one. That said, the latter can't have absolute value smaller than the others, but It can't be neither bigger nor in the middle. The last thing to prove is that eg $c=0$ gives nothing. Probably this is the ugly solution you refer to!

Comment: Nope, I was refering to the one below of user326188

Comment: Is this too badly written? Did you get the idea? I mean, seventh powers are too distant the one from the other, so even if you sum two positive seventh powers with one of them really small (or 0), there is no way to chose the negative one. This can be formalized with inequalities I guess.

Comment: Something like, let's say $a,b$ positive with $a\geq b$, $c$ negative, $a^7 + b^7 + c^7 \geq a^7 + c^7 \geq 2^7 - 1 > 45$, excluded few cases you must check.

Comment: $(a+h)^7-a^7\ge 2^7-1=127>45$ What more?

Comment: @Piquito and Maffred: it seems you are using $c<0 \implies c^7 \ge -1$, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seventh powers modulo $49$ are $0,\pm 1,\pm 18,\pm 19.$ There is no way to combine three of these to get $45$ modulo $49$.

Comment: ehm, how did you check that?

Comment: There's only 35 ways to sum three of these numbers and most of them do not even get close to $45$

Comment: I mean, how did you check the seventh powers of numbers up to 24?

Comment: Well, this was the ugly solution..

Comment: We are working mod $7^2$ so the seventh power only depends on $a$ mod $7$: $(7m+n)^7 = n^7 + 49mn + 7^2 * ... \equiv n^7$ mod $49$. So I only had to find seventh powers of $0,1,2,3$.